How can I add custom field the the Next Auth Google provider profile?
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas";
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";
import { getUserbyEmail } from "@/data/user";
import Github from "next-auth/providers/github";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";

export default {
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    Github({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
    Credentials({
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const validdatedFields = LoginSchema.safeParse(credentials);

        if (validdatedFields.success) {
          const { email, password } = validdatedFields.data;

          const user = await getUserbyEmail(email);
          if (!user || !user.password) return null;

          const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

          if (passwordsMatch) return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

I am building an app using Next AuthV5 for authentication, and I wanted to build a custom Google provider that returns more fields than just ID, name, image, and email (these are the default fields). In my use case, I have a username field that I would like to add to the Google provider. Next Auth says it's possible to return more information from the provider, but so far, I have had no luck.
Your would will be extremely appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

You can override profile for a provider. For my GitHubProvider, I have the following
export const githubProvider = GitHubProvider({
    id: "github"
    clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID || "",
    clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET || "",
    profile(profile: GithubProfile) {
        return {
            id: profile.id.toString(),
            name: profile.name || profile.login, // if user has not registered name
            roles: [], // custom stuff
            email: profile.email,
            image: profile.avatar_url,
        }
    }
})


